# How to plot function with undefined constant?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The example below plots exp(-x), but I would like to plot  lambda*exp(-x) instead, keeping lambda as an unknown variable and having the y axis span from 0 to lambda, as in the image below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!tbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $t$,
    ylabel = $x$,
    ]

    \addplot [
    domain=0:20, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
    ]
    {exp(-x)};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like all you need to do is change the labels on the axes.

To specify that you only want a single tick on the y axis at the position `y=1`, set `ytick = {1}`.

To specify that you want to label that position with λ, set `yticklabels = {$\lambda$}`.

To remove all tick marks from the x axis, set `xtick = \empty`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} % Nicer axis label placement

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $t$,
    ylabel = $x$,
    ymin = 0,
    ytick = {1},
    yticklabels = {$\lambda$},
    xtick = \empty,
    enlarge y limits = upper % Add some extra space at the top
]

\addplot [
    domain=0:5, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{exp(-x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{xfp}

% constants
\def\Lambda{5}
\def\xPoint{1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.55)(\fpeval{\Lambda+0.65},5.7)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(\fpeval{\Lambda+0.3},\fpeval{\Lambda+0.3})[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psplot[algebraic, linecolor = red]{0}{\Lambda}{\Lambda*Euler^(-x)}
  \uput[45](\xPoint,\fpeval{\Lambda*exp(-\xPoint)}){$y = \Lambda\exp(-x)$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is change the values of the constants and the drawing will be adjusted accordingly.